# 400 Bad Request in WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken MFP8

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I got bad request when I tried to register my device at MFP Server by calling WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken()

```
400 Bad Request - Invalid request body - JSON mapping failed.
```

Does anyone know what's the reason or how should I debug it. Is there any chances it caused by updating cordova-plugin-mfp?

I have no problem calling unprotected adapter method.

Comment: This issue is being checked. Are you using the latest release of MFP server? if not - update. If the problem persists, rollback to the previous cordova-plugin-mfp.

Comment: Thats helped alot! Appreciated it! Thanks @orepor

Comment: no problem. Which one was it exactly? updating your MFP server or moving to a previous cordova-plugin-mfp version?

Comment: moving to previous cordova-plugin-mfp version did helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 has had 2 beta releases (you can download beta 2 artifacts from: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/beta).

There are some compatibility issues between the client SDKs and the MFP Server between the beta releases. In your case, you need to update to beta 2.  In the coming release, MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 will be backward compatible so you will be able to use different versions between clients without needing to update the server.